# What is ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, midi, audio-player

Im trying to convert midi files to csv, make changes, and then change back into midi. I wan to do this all in python using the py_midicsv module.

However, I run into an error when i try to follow the documentation on: https://github.com/timwedde/py_midicsv

```
#Convert back to csv
import py_midicsv
csv_string = py_midicsv.midi_to_csv("example.mid")
midi_object = py_midicsv.csv_to_midi(csv_string)
```

The code above is straight from the documentations but I run into the error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-2cb6d586ec9e> in <module>
      1 #Convert back to csv
      2 import py_midicsv
----> 3 midi_object = py_midicsv.csv_to_midi(csv_string)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py_midicsv/csvmidi.py in parse(file)
     44             pattern.append(track)
     45         else:
---> 46             event = csv_to_midi_map[identifier](tr, time, identifier, line[3:])
     47             track.append(event)
     48     pattern.make_ticks_rel()

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py_midicsv/csv_converters.py in to_AfterTouchEvent(track, time, identifier, line)
     24 
     25 def to_AfterTouchEvent(track, time, identifier, line):
---> 26     cannel, value = map(int, line)
     27     return AfterTouchEvent(tick=time, channel=channel, value=value)
     28 

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

What does this error mean and how can I fix things?

Answer (score 2):

```
cannel, value = map(int, line)
```

the problem is with this line.
you are trying to unpack this `map` object into 2 objects, but it consists of more than 2 object, so python don't know what to do with the rest of the values.

you will need to understand what this `map` object contains, and what data you need to get from it. try to print it and see what data it holds.

Comment: And "channel" (which is used in the next line) is misspelled, so this part of the code was obviously never tested.